# React - deleting items from array not rendering correctly. Wrong items remain displayed

Tags: reactjs

I've created a simple react todo app, but I'm having an issue when deleting todo items in that they are remove from the array correctly being rendered incorrectly.

Example:

- create 4 to do items; "one", "two", "three" "four"
- select "one", "two" and delete these
- the array returns "three" and "four" as expected however "one" and "two" still appear
- this is the same for any number of selections in any order. The number selected always renders the first in the list i.e. don't delete 4 random out of 10 items and the first 4 items still remain in the list even if selected to remove.
- the only scenario I can get to work is to select all and all delete as expected

I've seen some similar issues where people didn't have an id/index but I have this in place.

I use context to update the to do tasks, Tasks component to list all tasks and have Task component for each individual task.
When I console log the tasks from each of these they all return the correct result therefore I can't figure out how to fix the correct rendering.

Link to the react-app: https://dan-mca.github.io/todo-app/

The below are the main files but all files can are on https://github.com/dan-mca/todo-app/

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**TasProvider.js**

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';

export const TaskContext = createContext([])

const TaskProvider = (props) => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])
  const [checkedTasks, setCheckedTasks] = useState([])

  const addCheckedTask = task => setCheckedTasks([...checkedTasks, task])

  const removeUncheckedTask = task => {
    const index = checkedTasks.findIndex(el => el.id === task.id)
    const checkedTasksCopy = [...checkedTasks]
    checkedTasksCopy.splice(index,1)

    setCheckedTasks(checkedTasksCopy)
  }

  const deleteTasks = (e) => {
    if(e.target.innerText === 'Delete' || e.target.id === 'Delete') {
      const filteredList = [...tasks].filter(task1 => ![...checkedTasks].find(task2 => task1.id === task2.id))
      setTasks(filteredList)
    }
  }

  const addTask = (task) => setTasks([...tasks, {id: tasks.length, taskText: task.taskText }])

  console.log(tasks)

  const data = {
    tasks,
    setTasks,
    addCheckedTask,
    removeUncheckedTask,
    checkedTasks,
    deleteTasks,
    addTask
  }
  return (
    <TaskContext.Provider value={data}>
      {props.children}
    </TaskContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default TaskProvider;
```

**Tasks.jsx**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { TaskContext } from '../../context/TasksProvider';
import Task from '../Task/Task'
import { TasksContainer, TasksHeader, TasksParagraph, TasksList } from './Tasks.styled'

const Tasks = () => {

  const taskContext = useContext(TaskContext)

  console.log(taskContext.tasks)

  return (
    <TasksContainer >
      <TasksHeader>Tasks</TasksHeader>
      { taskContext.tasks.length === 0 ?
          <TasksParagraph>All tasks have been completed. Great job!</TasksParagraph>
        : 
        <>
          <TasksList >
              { taskContext.tasks.map((task) => (
                <Task task={task} />
              ))
              }
          </TasksList>
          <TasksParagraph>Tasks to complete: {taskContext.tasks.length}</TasksParagraph> 
        </>
      }
    </TasksContainer>
  )
}

export default Tasks
```

**Task.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { TaskContext } from "../../context/TasksProvider";
import { TaskItem, TaskEditIcon, TaskInput, TaskInputContainer, TaskInputLabel, TaskInputCheckbox } from './Task.styled'

const Task = (props) => {
  const {task} = props;
  const taskContext = useContext(TaskContext)

  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)
  const [taskText, setTaskText] = useState(task.taskText)

  const handleClick = () => setIsClicked(!isClicked);

  const handleChange = (e) => setTaskText(e.target.value);

  const handleCheckboxclick = (e) => {

    if (e.target.checked === true) {
      taskContext.addCheckedTask({id: task.id, taskText})
    } else if (e.target.checked === false) {
      taskContext.removeUncheckedTask({id: task.id, taskText})
    }
  }

  console.log(task)
  
  return (
    <TaskItem key={task.id}>
      <TaskInputContainer>
        {
          isClicked ? 
            <TaskInput type="input" defaultValue={taskText} onChange={handleChange} id={task.id} />
          :
            <>
              <TaskInputCheckbox type="checkbox" id={task.id} onClick={handleCheckboxclick}/>
              <TaskInputLabel htmlfor={task.id}>{taskText}</TaskInputLabel>
            </>
        }
      </TaskInputContainer>
      <TaskEditIcon icon="clarity:edit-line" onClick={handleClick}/>
    </TaskItem>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

Comment: add  to <Task task={task} key={task.id} />

Comment: Thanks @OmarBerrami that fixed it! I did have key={index} before but removed it but didn't think to add this in. Won't forget this going forward. Thanks